# Route alias in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model stories in Rails 3.

I want to make an alias "books" for "stories" so I can have routes `/books/192` instead of `/stories/192`, and also that all my generated links (e.g. link_to) point to books' routes instead of stories' routes.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 113, accepted):

That's why they made the `path` option on `match` which is also available on `resources`:

```
resources :stories, :path => "books"
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is right. See [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers) This only changes helpers names. Run `rake routes` after inserting that line of code. It won't give what he is asking.

Comment: I believe Ryan Bigg is correct. However, there is a slight ambiguity in OP's question. When you say alias to a resource, it generally means that that resource is available via multiple routes. Thus, if you wanted your "stories resource" to be available via both "/stories" and "/books", then declaring something like this is also possible:

resources :stories, :as => :books
resources :books, :controller => "stories"

Thus, the "users of your app" get the same resource (stories) via two different routes ("/books", "/stories").

Comment: I know it's old, but I really don't understand how this answers the question. I can't get it to do anything of the sort. For me it just modifies the helper methods.

Comment: @MikeCampbell: Sorry, it was wrong. The correct option to use is `:path`.

Answer (score 127):

`resources :stories, :path => :books`

If you want to rename the path **AND** helper methods, then you do:

`resources :stories, :path => :books, :as => :books`

See: [Overriding the Named Helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-route-helpers)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying difference between `:path` & `:as`

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
match 'books/:id' => 'books#show'
match 'books' => 'books#index'
```

Comment: This is a hack, sorry to say. OP should use the `:as` option on `resources`.