# Rails one route, conditionally route views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We're building a custom cms and I was wondering if it's possible to have everything go through one route but to conditionally show a different view.  So for example, everything is an asset but the sub-type could be article, or video, etc.  Would it be possible to conditionally map to an article view?

Comment: I think you are looking for :as, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503550/route-alias-in-rails

Comment: Thanks for the response, although in our case I don't think we could make it as simple as that since it would be conditional on an attribute of the object.  So an asset with a content_type of "video" would go one way, "image" would go somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You can [render whatever you want](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render). ([Nutshell version](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#wrapping-it-up).)

It sort of sounds like some sort of class inheritance should have been used, though, and each should have their own controller/templates.

Comment: I would agree with you, my stance on it is that we should just have our articles etc, inherit from the asset but I don't have any say on system architecture, only on how and if we can do something.  If that makes sense.

Comment: It doesn't. If you're developing code on the system, you need the authority to change anything that gets in your way, including the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a good idea, if I understand correctly. Sounds like you're trying to reinvent Rails' routing system. Instead of reinventing it, use it!

If I misunderstand, please explain your use case in more detail.

Comment: I was asking because our team lead was wondering about routing with this method.  We're essentially having a front-end rendering system that de-normalizes the data into very few tables.  It's still in the planning process but we were wondering if this was even possible.

Comment: It's possible but a little pointless. Spend the effort learning to work *with* Rails' routing, not *against* it. Also, why the denormalization? Sounds smelly...