# How to add alias in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to add alias to route file?
Something like this:

```
/rules => 'posts/1', param: id => 1
```

Is it possible define it in routes.rb

I want

```
/rules => posts/1
```

not

```
/rules/1 => posts/1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Route alias in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503550/route-alias-in-rails)

Comment: i don't know how i can add param.
I want /rules => posts/1
not /rules/1 => posts/1

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's look at the official Rails [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults):

> You can also define other defaults in a route by supplying a hash for the :defaults option. This even applies to parameters that you do not specify as dynamic segments.

So then:

```
get "/rules" => "posts#show", :defaults => { :id => "1" }
```

Comment: this is better than my redirect solution :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
get '/rules', to: redirect('/posts/1')
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Comment: Better, but it must be redirect? I don't want see where redirect me. I'd like simple address /rules. That's all