# Change redmine routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

www.redmine.org

We use Redmine for asset tracking and I would like to update the URLs. Presently the URLs revolve around issues and does not look right for assets.

I would like to update it so that I would navigate to:

www.domain.com/assets instead of www.domain.com/issues

Using:
[Route alias in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503550/route-alias-in-rails)

I have looked at routes.rb and changed the line:

```
resources :issues do
```

to

```
resources :issues, :path => :assets do
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work...

**rake routes

```
rake routes | grep issues
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/htmlentities-4.3.1/lib/htmlentities/mappings/expanded.rb:465: warning: key "inodot" is duplicated and overwritten on line 466
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
                     preview_new_issue GET|POST|PUT|PATCH /issues/preview/new/:project_id(.:format)                                         previews#issue
                    preview_edit_issue GET|POST|PUT|PATCH /issues/preview/edit/:id(.:format)                                                previews#issue
                         preview_issue GET|POST|PUT|PATCH /issues/preview(.:format)                                                         previews#issue
                  auto_complete_issues GET                /issues/auto_complete(.:format)                                                   auto_completes#issues
                   issues_context_menu GET|POST           /issues/context_menu(.:format)                                                    context_menus#issues
                         issue_changes GET                /issues/changes(.:format)                                                         journals#index
                          quoted_issue POST               /issues/:id/quoted(.:format)                                                      journals#new {:id=>/\d+/}
                         project_gantt GET                /projects/:project_id/issues/gantt(.:format)                                      gantts#show
                          issues_gantt GET                /issues/gantt(.:format)                                                           gantts#show
                      project_calendar GET                /projects/:project_id/issues/calendar(.:format)                                   calendars#show
                       issues_calendar GET                /issues/calendar(.:format)                                                        calendars#show
                 project_issues_report GET                /projects/:id/issues/report(.:format)                                             reports#issue_report
         project_issues_report_details GET                /projects/:id/issues/report/:detail(.:format)                                     reports#issue_report_details
                     new_issues_import GET                /issues/imports/new(.:format)                                                     imports#new
                                       POST               /issues/:object_id/watchers(.:format)                                             watchers#create {:object_type=>"issue"}
                                       DELETE             /issues/:object_id/watchers/:user_id(.:format)                                    watchers#destroy {:object_type=>"issue"}
                    project_copy_issue GET                /projects/:project_id/issues/:copy_from/copy(.:format)                            issues#new
                        project_issues GET                /projects/:project_id/issues(.:format)                                            issues#index
                                       POST               /projects/:project_id/issues(.:format)                                            issues#create
                     new_project_issue GET                /projects/:project_id/issues/new(.:format)                                        issues#new
                    project_issues_new POST               /projects/:project_id/issues/new(.:format)                                        issues#new
                            edit_issue PATCH              /issues/:id/edit(.:format)                                                        issues#edit
                      bulk_edit_issues GET|POST           /issues/bulk_edit(.:format)                                                       issues#bulk_edit
                    bulk_update_issues POST               /issues/bulk_update(.:format)                                                     issues#bulk_update
             report_issue_time_entries GET                /issues/:issue_id/time_entries/report(.:format)                                   timelog#report
                    issue_time_entries GET                /issues/:issue_id/time_entries(.:format)                                          timelog#index
                                       POST               /issues/:issue_id/time_entries(.:format)                                          timelog#create
                  new_issue_time_entry GET                /issues/:issue_id/time_entries/new(.:format)                                      timelog#new
                       issue_relations GET                /issues/:issue_id/relations(.:format)                                             issue_relations#index
                                       POST               /issues/:issue_id/relations(.:format)                                             issue_relations#create
                                issues GET                /issues(.:format)                                                                 issues#index
                                       POST               /issues(.:format)                                                                 issues#create
                             new_issue GET                /issues/new(.:format)                                                             issues#new
                                       GET                /issues/:id/edit(.:format)                                                        issues#edit
                                 issue GET                /issues/:id(.:format)                                                             issues#show
                                       PATCH              /issues/:id(.:format)                                                             issues#update
                                       PUT                /issues/:id(.:format)                                                             issues#update
                                       DELETE             /issues/:id(.:format)                                                             issues#destroy
                            issues_new POST               /issues/new(.:format)                                                             issues#new
                                       DELETE             /issues(.:format)                                                                 issues#destroy
                                       POST               /projects/:id/repository/:repository_id/revisions/:rev/issues(.:format)           repositories#add_related_issue
                                       DELETE             /projects/:id/repository/:repository_id/revisions/:rev/issues/:issue_id(.:format) repositories#remove_related_issue
                                       POST               /projects/:id/repository/revisions/:rev/issues(.:format)                          repositories#add_related_issue
                                       DELETE             /projects/:id/repository/revisions/:rev/issues/:issue_id(.:format)                repositories#remove_related_issue
```

Comment: run rake routes command and add it to your question. and try with resources :issues, :path => :assets, :as => :assets

Comment: worked thank you. I did not know I could have multiple "resources" statements for the same resource, I thought I had to amend the existing one.

Comment: I note that only the plural of the route works and not the singular form. I would like to be able to use www.domain.com/assets & www.domain.com/asset/100, Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But conventionally model name should be singular and controller name must be plural . So, as controller name will be plural your routes too. But you can change it if you want to do.